# How do I return negative value from data-value attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I have an upvote/downvote buttons with `data-value` attribute with `1` and `-1` as values.

I am using `$(this).children().attr('data-value')` to get the values and submit the to the database, but it is always return a positive value even when all I've done was downvote posts.

I have also tried using `$(this).children().data('value')` with the same result.

I am using [jquery.upvote.js](https://github.com/janosgyerik/jquery-upvote)

The form

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => 'votes', 'class' => 'votes']) !!}
   <div class="upvote topic" data-post="{{ $post->id }}">
    <a class="upvote vote" data-value="1"></a>
    <span class="count">0</span>
    <a class="downvote vote" data-value="-1"></a>
   </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Javascript

```
$('.topic').upvote();

$('.topic').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {value: $(this).children().attr('data-value'), post_id: $(this).data('post')};

    var clicked_button = $(this).children();

    if($(clicked_button).hasClass('downvote-on')) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('[name="_token"]').val()
      }
    });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost/laravel-5/public/votes',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: data
     });
     } else if ($(clicked_button).hasClass('upvote-on')) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('[name="_token"]').val()
           }
     });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://localhost/laravel-5/public/votes',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: data
     });
    }
   });
```

Comment: TRy this . $(".downvote").getAttribute("data-value");

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).getAttribute is not a function`

Comment: Praveen has the point I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking your code closely, I can see that the handler is attached to the `<div>` instead of `<a>`. When there's more than one `<a>` tag, this would take the last one. So make sure you attach the event hander to `<a>` and not any others.

```
$('.topic .vote').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {value: $(this).attr('data-value')
```

---

Try to use `$(element).data("value")` instead.

Check out the below fiddle:

```js
$(function () {
  $("a").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("attr: " + $(this).attr("data-value") + "\ndata: " + $(this).data("value"));
  });
});
```

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
a {text-decoration: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<p><a href="#" data-value="-1">Get Data (-1)</a></p>
<p><a href="#" data-value="1">Get Data (1)</a></p>
```

Comment: I cannot attach the events to the `<a>` tags because I still need to get the `post_id` from another tag.

Comment: Maybe you can add postid to a tags too.

Comment: @Halnex Can you delegate the events? From where you are getting the `post_id`? Use `$(this).closest("div").find(whatever)`?

Comment: I just tried your snippet, it stopped submitting the database all together. I must say that I am using jquery.upvote.js to display the upvote buttons and it needs to call the class `topic` on the div in order to work.

Comment: Use parent function to get the parent div of the respective element and then get the attribute.

Comment: Or from the `a` tag, you can go back to the parentNode and get your post_id

Comment: This `$('a').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var data = {value: $('.vote').data('value'), post_id: $(this).parent().data('post')};` is not working

Comment: @Halnex Can you post the full fiddle somewhere?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar It's already in the original post. But here you go anyway https://jsfiddle.net/8328pa5s/

Comment: @Halnex I did saw it. Does it work for you? It is useless for me.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't think it's going to work on there, I am using Laravel helpers there and submitting ajax requests to the database. You would have to download jquery.upvote.js and try it locally, the snippet code can be found on https://github.com/janosgyerik/jquery-upvote - instead of ajax request do `console.log`

Comment: @Halnex I perfectly understand that. What exactly you want to happen. I have a local copy of it.

Comment: I have added `data-value` attribute to each of the `<a>` tags, I'd like to be able to return a negative value from the downvote button, so far it is getting a positive value from there.

Comment: @Halnex You have given the `click` event on the `div` and you are getting the value by using `$(this).children('[data-value]')`, which gives the first link, that has `+1`.

Comment: But I have no other choice, if I change the click event to use the `<a>` tag instead, the plugin will stop working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89966/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-halnex).